# How do I subtract a value in the dictionary?

Tags: python

The generation of dictionary from the function is below:

- The function will execute the mysql query

  output = {}
  def s(a,b,c):
      output = {a:[b,c]}
      return output

a,b,c are coming from the database `cursor = connection.cursor();cursor.execute(query)`

my dictionary return `output` is below

```
{'a':['test','10']}
{'b':['test','5']}
```

How to subtract the values in the dictionary `10 - 5`

my code is below

```
k = []
for i,j in s.items():
   k.append(j[1])

My output is `['10'],['10']`
```

Comment: Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the code declares two dicts without assigning them to variables, they get constructed and destructed.Nowhere is any subtraction done. please [edit] a real [mre] into your question so we can see where your problem is

Comment: How is appending supposed to subtract anything? Your code seems to be unrelated to the (not quite clear) problem that it is trying to solve.

Comment: Are you asking how to access `c` in `{a:[b,c]}`? Your code suggests that you already know that, so your question remains mysterious. Your question is also obscure since you seem to have some unspecified variable `result`. Is this variable a tuple of dictionaries? Is it a dictionary of dictionaries? If so, it isn't clear what it has to do with your function `s` (since that would generate a dictionary whose values are dictionaries, not a dictionary whose values are dictionaries). But -- you describe `result` as the output of `s`. How so?

Comment: @JohnColeman ,its understandable that these variables are coming from some where. i have added some more details

Comment: You seem to be changing the question. In a comment to one of the answers you wrote "its coming from one variable only called result" but when i ask you information about what `result` is, you seem to have dropped all references to it, but instead call it `output`, but it still isn't clear what it is. How is the variable `output` defined and what does it contain?  Are you reassigning `output` so that it first stands for `{'a':['test','10']}` and then, later on, stands for `{'b':['test','5']}`? Why not give a [mcve] (please read that link) which shows exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your dictionary is called `test_dict`.

This will give you desired result.

```
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(lambda x,y: x-y, [int(i[1]) for i in test_dict.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store your dictionaries in a variable otherwise you can't access them later one. Store them as variables first:

```
a = {'a':['test','10']}
b = {'b':['test','5']}

Then grab the numbers
num_a = a["a"][1] --> outputs "10"
num_b = b["b"][1] --> outputs "5"

# convert to int and subtract
int(num_a) - int(num_b)
```

Comment: its coming from one variable only called result