# How to subtract the values inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I have dictionary below

```
d = {'1': {'index': '1', 'sc': '4', 'st': '3'}, 
'2': {'index': '2', 'sc': '5', 'st': '5'}}
```

I need to create a new key `diff` with subtract `sc - st`

expected out

```
d1 = {'1': {'index': '1', 'sc': '4', 'st': '3', 'diff': 1}, 
    '2': {'index': '2', 'sc': '5', 'st': '5', 'diff': 0}}

d2 = {'1':{'diff': 1}, '2': {'diff': 0}}
```

Pseudo code

```
from functools import reduce
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
for i,j in m.items():
    #print (j)
    for a,b in j.items():
        #print (b)
        d1['diff'] =  reduce(lambda x,y: x-y, [int(i) for i in d.values()])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract a value in the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61985480/how-to-subtract-a-value-in-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
d1 = {k: {**v, "diff": int(v['sc']) - int(v['st'])} for k, v in d.items()}
d2 = {k: {"diff": int(v['sc']) - int(v['st'])} for k, v in d.items()}
```

Result

```
d1 = {'1': {'index': '1', 'sc': '4', 'st': '3', 'diff': 1}, '2': {'index': '2', 'sc': '5', 'st': '5', 'diff': 0}}

d2 = {'1': {'diff': 1}, '2': {'diff': 0}}
```